# Oracle Database is not starting

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

I have a problem with running Oracle database. I've installed Oracle Database 18c Express Edition and it's not working.

There is `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error` when I use `sqlplus / as sysdba`

I tried running it by windows service ([error like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLFNS.png)) and also using lsnrctl services commend ([error like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW9BP.png)) .

Answer (score 0):

Your database is not up and running.

Just goto `command prompt` and follow the steps

```
1. Set Oracle SID C:>set oracle_sid=ORCL

2. run Net start command. C:>net start oracleserviceORCL
```

Comment: For these commends, I get "The service name is invalid.".
If I change ORCL to XE, I get "The requested service has already been started".

Comment: @Sienki what are you giving as user_name? e.g. for me username `zeal/roww@orcl` works but when I give username as `zeal/roww` throws an error `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`

Comment: I don't give any username. There wasn't a possibility to create a user during the installation. So I took for granted that username isn't needed.

Comment: I think that's the issue then. try to run thi `c:\> sqlplus login/password@XE` and see if it prompt you to enter username and password?

Comment: I have ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred, but also it prompt me to eneter username. I'm confused.